# How to let DjangoModelFactory create a model without saving it to the DB?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, factory, factory-boy

I'm writing unit tests in a Django project. I've got a factory to create objects using the `.create()` method. So in my unit tests I'm using this:

```
device = DeviceFactory.create()
```

This always creates a record in the DB though. Is there a way that I can make the factory create an object without saving it to the DB yet?

I looked over the documentation but I can't find it. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Quoth [this bit of the documentation](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#using-factories), use `.build()` instead of `.create()`:

```py
# Returns a User instance that's not saved
user = UserFactory.build()

# Returns a saved User instance.
# UserFactory must subclass an ORM base class, such as DjangoModelFactory.
user = UserFactory.create()

# Returns a stub object (just a bunch of attributes)
obj = UserFactory.stub()

# You can use the Factory class as a shortcut for the default build strategy:
# Same as UserFactory.create()
user = UserFactory()
```

Comment: Haha, happens to the best of us. :)